# Commutative diagram: get an arrow to 'skip' an object

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

```
    $$\begin{tikzcd} A\ar[r,shift left,"f"] 
&\ar[l,shift left,"h"] B\ar[r,shift left,"g"] 
&\ar[l,shift left,"l"]\ar[l,bend left, shift left,"h"] 
C\end{tikzcd}$$
```

[image]

This is almost as I'd like it to be, except that the $h$ arrow is going from $C$ to $B$ rather than from $C$ to $A$. How can I modify the code so it does that?

EDIT: accidentally called two arrows 'h'. This was not intentional, but I think the text makes it clear which one I'm referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ll` in `\ar[ll,bend left, shift left,"h"]`. Two `l`s mean that the arrow should go two positions to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
      \[\begin{tikzcd} A\ar[r,shift left,"f"]
            &\ar[l,shift left,"h"] B\ar[r,shift left,"g"]
            &\ar[l,shift left,"l"]\ar[ll,bend left, shift left,"h"] C
        \end{tikzcd}
      \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And in LaTeX, don't use `$$...$$`, use `\[...\]` as the saying goes....

Comment: That's for the answer. But what's the advantage of \[ \backslash [...\backslash ]\]?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt: Please see: [Why is \\[ ... \\] preferable to $$ ... $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854)

Comment: Had never heard of that. Thanks, will be sure to use it in the future!

Comment: What if I'm just writing the name of a function? Say I want to refer to the function $f$. Is it ok to write f between two dollar signs, or is there a preferable way to do it?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt `$` are plain TeX primitives. `$f$` will be `\(f\)` in LaTeX and `$$f$$` will be `\[f\]`. However, `$f$` is more widely used and doesn't have much drawbaacks as its `$$` cousin.